# Capturar contenido de comentario HTML con expresiones regulares en Python

Tags: python, regex

Muy buenos días. Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema. A modo de ejemplo, tengo la siguiente cadena de caracteres:

```
aux = "Hola mundo <!-- %&$#/(&%$%&/%%&&%//heiqdqoi%%/ --> cadena de prueba"
```

Qué expresión regular debería utilizar para seleccionar el comentario? Todo lo que esté adentro del "". Lo que estoy haciendo es esto:

```
import re

prueba = re.findall(r"<!--.*?-->", aux)
```

Pero no me está seleccionando nada. He probado con otras combinaciones pero nada me está funcionando. Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Si estás tratando de parsear html con regex, te recomiendo que busques un parser que lea los comentarios html. Las regex no suelen ser buena idea para parsear lenguajes y puede llegar a darte falsos positivos o falsos negativos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo tienes casi en tu propia expresión regular. Recuerda que para definir grupos de captura, necesitas incluir los paréntesis:

```
re.findall(r"<!--(.*)-->", aux)
```

Si te ha servido esta respuesta, no olvides puntuarla :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me funcionó!

Comment: Te hago una consulta... La cuestión es que tengo un string, bastante mas largo que el del ejemplo. Lo que busco es lo mismo planteado mas arriba, pero, en mi string hay varios "\n". Ahora, cuando aplico la expresión 'r"<!--(.*)-->"' al ejemplo de una sola línea que plantee mas arriba me funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo aplico a la cadena con saltos de línea no me devuelve nada. Mi pregunta es, como afectan los saltos de líneas a las expresiones regulares? Debería quitarlos todos? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Si solo deseas tomar el comentario interno en el String la expresión que necesitas es:

```
([<!-->])+
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: No probé tu regex, pero me parece que no funcionaría correctamente. Lo que ofreces lee una o más veces cualquiera de los caracteres "<!-->", pero el op quiere leer el comentario de por si. Aun así, gracias por tu aporte c:

Comment: Si bien me devolvió el comentario, también me devolvió todos los "<" y ">" entre otros. Muchas gracias de todas maneras. Aunque claro la idea sería poder devolver exclusivamente el comentario. En realidad el problema que tenía que resolver ya lo resolví pero quiero hacerlo de forma mas prolija